# Taking contents of an array of objects, and assigning them to a property on a JSON object

Tags: javascript

I want to take items from this array (the way I save things on the client)

```
[
    {
        "id": "-Mdawqllf_-BaW63gMMM",
        "text": "Finish the backend[1]",
        "status": true,
        "time": 1625248047800
    },
    {
        "id": "-Mdawqllf_-BaW63gGHf",
        "text": "Finish the middle-end[2]",
        "status": false,
        "time": 1625248040000
    },
    {
        "id": "-Mdawqllf_-BaW63gGHd",
        "text": "Finish the front-end[3]",
        "status": false,
        "time": 1625248040000
    }
]
```

And turn them into this format for how I save it server side

```
{    "todos": {
            "-Mdawqllf_-BaW63gMMM": {
                "text": "Finish the backend[1]",
                "status": true,
                "time": 1625248047800,
                
            },
            "-Mdawqllf_-BaW63gGHf": {
                "text": "Finish the middle-end[2]",
                "status": false,
                "time": 1625248040000,
                
            },
            "-Mdawqllf_-BaW63gGHd": {
                "text": "Finish the front-end[3]",
                "status": false,
                "time": 1625248040000,
                
            }
        },
}
```

Basically i turn items into an array on the client to help with sorting and making use of arrays. But before sending it back need to put into the right format

Comment: Where do the `index` values come from in the result? They're not the original array indexes.

Comment: Removed them as they are irrelevant to the example

Answer (score 1):

Use `.map()` to loop over the array of objects to exctract the `id` property, so you can use it as the key of the new object.

Use `Object.fromEntries()` to create the new object from the array returned by `.map()`.

```js
const data = [
    {
        "id": "-Mdawqllf_-BaW63gMMM",
        "text": "Finish the backend[1]",
        "status": true,
        "time": 1625248047800
    },
    {
        "id": "-Mdawqllf_-BaW63gGHf",
        "text": "Finish the middle-end[2]",
        "status": false,
        "time": 1625248040000
    },
    {
        "id": "-Mdawqllf_-BaW63gGHd",
        "text": "Finish the front-end[3]",
        "status": false,
        "time": 1625248040000
    }
];

const todos = {
  Todos: Object.fromEntries(data.map(obj => [obj.id, obj]))
};

console.log(todos);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this only accounts for the first object within the array

Comment: There's only one object in the array.

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to merge all the objects in the array.

Comment: Ah you are right and sorry that was my mistake when setting up the question.

Remove the enclosing {} so its [{...},{...},{...}] - thats what i have, an array of three objects that I would like to then have assigned to {todos: Assign here} 

Thanks for your help thus far - really appreciated

Comment: What you've written now is not valid JavaScript. You can't have `key: value` in an array, only in an object.

Comment: I'm so stupid, you are 100% right. I was taking the data from the wrong place but have edited the question to be correct. Sorry for wasting your time but the question should now be correct.

Comment: You've completely changed the question now, I've written a new answer.

Comment: Barmar you are a legend! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
const items = {
      todos: {
           ...data
      }
 };
```

Assume that data is the array of objects.
Use the spread operator to copy all the array objects from data array to the todos object at key **todos**.

One important thing to note that you can't assign more than one objects without array to a single object key. You definately have to use the array to maintain all the objects under the one key.

Avoid using the hardcode index. Always use the spread operator

Comment: Unfortunately I'm trying to have it not be an array.. Essentially all i want to do is remove the [ ], I also thought destructuring could help but it always come back as an array

Comment: @kasmo Obviously dear you can't assign more than one value to a key of object without array. You have to be use the array

Comment: Muhammad, I'm so stupid, you are 100% right. I was taking the data from the wrong place but have edited the question to be correct. Sorry for wasting your time but the question should now be correct.

Comment: @kasmo Hi Mate ! I just edited answer. Now you can get all the objects from main array and store all objects inside object at the key todo. I hope this will work for you

Answer (score 0):

@Barmar's solutions is nice.

For the sake of learning or others googling. You can also reduce the array to an object.

```
const todos = data.reduce((obj, item) => {
  obj[item.id] = item
  return obj
}, {})
```